# Starting multiple untracked flows with the Corda RPC Client

Tags: corda

In an application which is loading data in a batch process, how can Corda trigger many flows in parallel without tracking or observables?

On the RPC client there are only two methods (startFlowDynamic and startTrackedFlowDynamic) https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.messaging/-corda-r-p-c-ops/index.html

The goal is to avoid unnecessary overhead and run many flows in parallel. When tracked flows are used Corda deliver a warning about unused listeners: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3.2/client/rpc/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/client/rpc/internal/RPCClientProxyHandler.kt#L143

Answer (score 1):

The warning that you're seeing when using `startTrackedFlowDynamic` is occurring because it returns several `Observable`s that are not being used. As the warning says, you will need to manually close the unused ones by subscribing and then subscribing from them or use the helper method `net.corda.client.rpc.UtilsKt#notUsed`.

With regardings to running multiple flows in parallel then you can do something like this:

```
FlowHandle<Result> flowHandle1 = rpcProxy.startFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.class, *flow parameters 1*);
FlowHandle<Result> flowHandle2 = rpcProxy.startFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.class, *flow parameters 2*);
FlowHandle<Result> flowHandle3 = rpcProxy.startFlowDynamic(ExampleFlow.class, *flow parameters 3*);
```

Then you can wait for all of them to complete by simply waiting on each result `Future` object in turn:

```
Arrays.asList(flowHandle1, flowHandle2, flowHandle3).forEach(handle -> {
  handle.getReturnValue().get();
});
```